# Gradle Wrapper not responding to commands

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradlew

On my Linux machine in my root project directory I have the Gradle Wrapper

```
Project
 |
 + src
 |
 + gradlew
```

and when I run any command with `gradlew` there is no output, like for example when I print the version, there is no version printed

```
./gradlew --version
```

or when I check tasks, no tasks are displayed

```
./gradlew --tasks
```

or when I try to build the project, no `out/` directory is created

```
./gradlew deploy
```

but when I click

```
Build > Build Project
```

in my Intellij IDE, the project does build, just not when I try to use Gradle from the command line.

So I have no idea what's going on with my gradle wrapper. Am I using the wrapper incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My gradle wrapper which is just a Bash script, was empty ... somehow it's contents were deleted, so the script was running and nothing was happening. Good times.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me as well, the script was totally empty. The fix for me was to go to the gradle tab in IntelliJ and click on "Wrapper" under "Build setup".
After this my gradlew script got properly initialized.

[image: see on image]